# Broken front driver's side suspension

Tags: suspension, mini-cooper

I have hit a pothole on way home tonight and now driver side is low and arch rubbing on wheel and grinding when I turn left anyone got idea what I broke please

Comment: If you get down low, I suspect you can take pictures of what might have broken.  That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without pictures. Based on what you said I would speculate it is definitely suspension related. Badly damaged or destroyed shock absorber-, MacPherson strut (another type of shock absorber configuration), broken coil spring, stabilizer link snapped in two are my guesses. Must have been one hell of a pothole.

Comment: It was and I didn't see it until it was too late  as it was pitch black would you  have any idea what it would cost it's a 06 reg mini

Comment: @Polly - There's really no way to know how much it's going to cost to fix something. It could be a couple hundred to several thousand quid/dollar/denero/juan/[insert currency of choice].